# Postgres - Combining data from 2 different tables into 1 table

Tags: database, postgresql, join

I would like to combine data from 2 completely different table.

Table 1

```
   id  |       Name       |      X     
-------+------------------+---------------
     1 |   AAAAAAAAAAAA   |   Sample
     2 |   AAAAAAAAAAAA   |   Sample    
     3 |   AAAAAAAAAAAA   |   Sample
```

Table 2

```
   id  |       Name    
-------+------------------
     4 |   BBBBBBBBBBBB       
     5 |   BBBBBBBBBBBB        
     6 |   BBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Expected Result

```
       Name       |      X     
------------------+---------------
   AAAAAAAAAAAA   |    Sample  
   AAAAAAAAAAAA   |    Sample  
   AAAAAAAAAAAA   |    Sample  
   BBBBBBBBBBBB   |     null 
   BBBBBBBBBBBB   |     null 
   BBBBBBBBBBBB   |     null
```

Is this possible? I've been reading examples but almost all of them have ids where the tables' data match.

Also, is it possible to use specific value on 'X' column?

I've tried using

```
SELECT
    Name,
    X
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT
   Name,
   "string" as X
FROM table;
```

but I am getting an error. "Column "string" does not exist".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use single quotes instead of double quotes

```
SELECT
    Name,X
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Name,'string' as X
FROM table;
```

Comment: geez. that was stupid of me. thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

From your expected output, it actually looks like you don't want any value for `X` in the second table:

```
SELECT Name, X FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, NULL FROM table2
ORDER BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.
Two mistakes:

1. UNION ALL instead of UNION since UNION ignores duplicate values.
2. NULL instead of 'string' because you can use the literal NULL in a SELECT statement.

```sql
SELECT
    Name,
    X
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT
   Name,
   NULL
FROM table;
```

Refer to this [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4c9e4340586f338b9c1a71baa82dee1e)